# What does the use_subprocess argument do in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

What does the use_subprocess argument do in this line of code?

`driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=chrome_options)`

I have looked for a while but i cant find anything

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium, the use_subprocess argument is used in the webdriver.Chrome constructor when initializing a Chrome WebDriver instance. This argument determines whether Selenium should use a subprocess for running the Chrome browser.

When use_subprocess is set to True, Selenium will spawn a separate subprocess to control the Chrome browser. This can be useful for isolating the WebDriver process from the browser process, which can help with stability and security. However, using a subprocess might have some performance overhead.

On the other hand, when use_subprocess is set to False, Selenium will attempt to connect directly to an existing instance of Chrome if it's already running on the system. This can be faster since it doesn't involve launching a new subprocess, but it may have limitations depending on the environment and configurations.